# How to download file mp4 from google drive api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client, flysystem-google-drive

I'm building a server using nodejs and I want the server to response mp4 file downloaded from the google drive api

Comment: Please edit your question include the code you are currently using and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example of downloading a file from the DriveAPI here:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/download.js

Hope this helps!